# How to fix setState asynchronous issue?

Tags: reactjs

```
function Test() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  const handler = () => {
    setState(1);
    console.log(state);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>My state: {state}</div>
      <button onClick={handler}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know that React.useState is asynchronous, but i don't fully undestand how it works.
In my example in handler function I need to console.log new state (1) after setState(1), but it's logging 0. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

`setState` isn't asynchronous, but the value will only be updated when a new render is triggered (to batch multiple updates).

```
function Test() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  const handler = () => {
    setState(1);
  }

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>My state: {state}</div>
      <button onClick={handler}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way you will see the new value logged. There is no way to get the updated value inside the handler even with `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use an callback function, so that it will update accordingly. In react functional component you can achieve this by `useEffect` hook.

```
 useEffect(()=>{
      console.log(state);
    },[state])
```

Now it will render the component, whenever the state changes